# Show result from when the test is over

Tags: c#

I don't know how to solve this issue, I have 105 radiobuttons with different questions, I want to collect all the correct answers, when the users are done they can hit a button I have made thats called "submit test", but I want it to display a messagebox with the reults.

So far, this is what I have got to gather points:

```
 if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            Score.Add(0);
        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            Score.Add(0);
        }
        else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
        {
            Score.Add(1);
```

I have made a list to store all of the right answers, List Scores = new List();

And this is my code for the button "submit" it is in swedish LämnaIn:

```
       private void LämnaIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Är du säker på att du vill lämna in?", Text, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Score.Count; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Score.Count.ToString()); 
            }
                   
            this.Close();
        }
        else if (res == DialogResult.No)
        {
            LämnaIn.Enabled = true;
        }
```

To count the Scores and to show a percentage in the messagebox above I have this code:

```
    private void Math(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int sum = Score.Sum();
        int count = Score.Count();

        double score = sum / count * 100;
    }
```

If someone can help I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with lots of controls, it's useful work with sets instead of Visual Studio generated controls. We can start with a class that encapsulate a Question. In the GUI, this is a GroupBox with some RadioButtons. Also, we encapsulate here when the response is valid or not. Let's see the code for this class:

```
public class QuestionGroup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Index of the valid response.
    /// </summary>
    private int _validResponseIndex;

    public QuestionGroup(string questionText)
    {
        this.GroupBox = new GroupBox
        {
            TabStop = false,
            Text = questionText
        };

        this.GroupBox.Location = new Point(12, 12);
        this.GroupBox.Size = new Size(300, 30);
        this.GroupBox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Instance of the group control.
    /// </summary>
    public GroupBox GroupBox { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates if response is valid.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsValidResponse => this._validResponseIndex >= 0 &&
        ((RadioButton)this.GroupBox.Controls[this._validResponseIndex]).Checked;

    /// <summary>
    /// Add an option to available responses.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">Response text.</param>
    /// <param name="isValidResponse"><c>true</c> if this is the valid response to the question.</param>
    public QuestionGroup AddButton(string text, bool isValidResponse = false)
    {
        const int top = 21;
        const int height = 27;

        if (isValidResponse)
        {
            this._validResponseIndex = this.GroupBox.Controls.Count;
        }

        var radioButton = new RadioButton
        {
            AutoSize = true,
            UseVisualStyleBackColor = true,
            TabStop = true,
            TabIndex = this.GroupBox.Controls.Count,
            Location = new Point(6, top + this.GroupBox.Controls.Count * height),
            Text = text
        };

        this.GroupBox.Controls.Add(radioButton);
        this.GroupBox.Height += height;

        return this;
    }
}
```

We have the question text, that it's show as the GroupBox text. The AddButton allow us add a response for the question. You need include the text and also add a true when the response is the valid one. We are using GroupBox.Controls to know how many responses have que question. GroupBox is exposed to allow set size, position... outside.

Now create an empty form and add this code to check the previous class:

```
public partial class QuestionsForm : Form
{
    private readonly List<QuestionGroup> _questions;

    public QuestionsForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this._questions = new List<QuestionGroup>();

        var question = new QuestionGroup("Question 1")
            .AddButton("Response 1")
            .AddButton("Response 2")
            .AddButton("Response 3", true);
        this.AddQuestion(question);

        question = new QuestionGroup("Question 2")
            .AddButton("Response 10")
            .AddButton("Response 20", true)
            .AddButton("Response 30");
        this.AddQuestion(question);
    }

    private void AddQuestion(QuestionGroup question)
    {
        var previousQuestion = this._questions.Count > 0 ? this._questions[this._questions.Count - 1] : null;
        var top = previousQuestion != null ? previousQuestion.GroupBox.Bottom + 12 : 12;

        question.GroupBox.TabIndex = this._questions.Count;
        question.GroupBox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
        question.GroupBox.Location = new Point(12, top);
        question.GroupBox.Size = new Size(this.ClientSize.Width - 24, question.GroupBox.Height);

        this._questions.Add(question);
        this.Controls.Add(question.GroupBox);
    }

    private void CheckResults()
    {
        var validResponsesCount = this._questions.Count(q => q.IsValidResponse);

        var text = string.Format(
            "{0} of {1} questions correct. Score = {2:0.##}", 
            validResponsesCount,
            this._questions.Count,
            validResponsesCount / (double)this._questions.Count);
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }
}
```

Each item in _questions is a Question. So _questions.Count is the total of questions. We can create as many Questions as we need. AddButton return the QuestionGroup: we can add all responses concatenating AddButton methods in a fluent way. In one of the responses we set true to indicate the valid response.

The AddQuestion method in the form is used to set the position... of each question. This is only an example. You may need to adapt to your concrete case.

The CheckResults method give you the message with total questions and valid responses. You may invoke from a button click, for example.

**UPDATE**

You must try to understand the code before integrate it with your code. Your form is a partial class, so part of the code is in the Form1.Designer.cs file. Check the code in this file and you can see how the groups and radio buttons are created and positioned in the form.

When you work with a few controls, is very comfortable the Form designer. With some clicks you design your interface. But when you need create controls at runtime or work with lots of controls, maybe easier create a class to encapsulate the repetitive tasks and give some properties that are useful for you.

Review my code and compare with the designer code. You'll see that I create a RadioGroup and the designer too. I create 3 radios in each group, like your designer. I do the same. But I create a group with 3 radios in one sentence (4 lines of code) and add some important property for you: the valid response. So I can create the controls easily and remember the valid response. All managed in QuestionGroup class.

If you check that class, you can see that the RadioGroup is a public property. I do that to allow you move the RadioGroup, put in the location that you prefer. In my example, I put a group at 12 pixels and next groups just below the previous one. All in one column. You must do the same, with a fixed width (instead of the Anchor that I use) and after X groups, start again at top in the next column.

At the end, I simply remove duplicated code in the designer. But this kind of things are very important to manage code.

Create another form in your project (right click -> Add form) and try to replicate your Form1 in that form using my approach. You can do a "new Form2()" and invoke Show in your Form1 constructor to test or change Form1 to Form2 in program.cs. You are starting with this and it's important do the things by yourself, try and fix, one and again.